# Do I have to write snarky disclaimers when posting questions that look like a duplicate at the first glance?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, closed-questions

Several times I've been posting a question regarding a matter that has been solved a) in similar language or similar platform (eg. browser vs Node.js) or b) solved generally but not in my specific case.

Lazy people tend to close those questions before even reading them carefully. It almost seems I will have to make it practice to begin such questions with:

> **This is not a duplicate of ...:** The other post solves the problem for ... but not for ... when ...
>
> ---
>
> *... question starts here ...*

Which is something I eventually have to add anyway. And it makes me pissed. I prefer the post to be consistent text that can be read from beginning to the end, without any appendixes or prependixes.

But how else can I deter people from closing a question before fully considering whether the "duplicate" solves the problem or just has similar title?

<sub>Note that I didn't mention any specific questions because I do not want to trigger the Meta effect (either way) and I am confident the question will be reopened anyway, as all the past questions of this type were.</sub>

Comment: You could try.  All disclaimers make me downvote immediate and move on to the next question.  Why bother doing any more than that?  To look at the OP issue, it means reading two questions instead of one and trying to understand the differences before even starting to analyse the OP's problem/s.  Too much, downvote. closevote, next....

Comment: 'deter people from closing a question before reading it?' - do people do that?  Do you have any evidence, (no)?

Comment: @MartinJames I just got question immediatelly reopened after being closed by three different people. Not the first time. It was exageratiion and possibly unfair to claim that they didn't read it, but they obviously didn't really think about it enough, otherwise they "possible duplicate" would never be suggested. Of course, putting the *in your face* disclaimer got the question reopened immediately.

Comment: I edited the question to remove the unfair claim about people not reading the questions.

Comment: Related on Meta.SE: [Someone flagged my question as already answered but it's not](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/194476)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could probably say the same thing with less "snark" (or really, just integrate it into your post a bit better).

> I know how to solve this problem in the common case (as described in [solutions for the common case of this problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320108/do-i-have-to-write-snarky-disclaimers-when-posting-questions-that-look-like-a-du)), but today the problem I face has one crucial difference which makes all those solutions inapplicable...

...Or something like that. The goal here is to show the research you've done, the existing posts that seem like they *could* have helped but which didn't. This not only wards off lazy closers, it helps folks who might answer to avoid wasting their time on dead-ends.

Comment: Even when I mentioned questions that didn't work form me it wasn't 100% reliable, though of course it's good thing to show that I've read them already. If I could list my reopened question I could even find those...

Comment: My point is, putting that information front and center isn't in and of itself a bad thing, so don't look at it as a blight on your question, since it's potentially helpful to answerers (and also future readers). If you find your presentation off-putting, work on that instead.

Comment: Still won't work.  Too many SO'ers are like Mr. James above, and you wind up bothering them by asking questions.

Comment: If you play to jackasses, your audience will consist entirely of jackasses, @Yet. Play to those acting in good faith and you may find that the folks you thought were here for the jackassery are in fact willing to stay for something useful.

Comment: That might be true in general, but isn't my experience with SO and SO-culture, especially after reading tons of meta posts of people making similar comments as Mr James'.

Comment: Again, you get the audience you play for, @Yet - here and everywhere else. Lots of folks come in with the attitude that snark is the best response to any situation, and sure enough they get folks who eat that up and react accordingly - so if you don't like the attitude, then don't play the tune.